# How to tell the amount of times a pypi package is downloaded by actual users?

Tags: python, pypi

I uploaded a Python package to *PyPI* and I would like to track how many "real" downloads it has. Like, given that my package has, say, 1000 downloads (per day, week, month, doesn't matter), I would like to discard from that amount the number of downloads made from CI servers and so. I mean, I would like to discard downloads that are not from actual users.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: The notion of "actual users" is hard to define. When I set up my fifth virtualenv this month and let `pip` download the requirements automatically, is that a download by a user? When I script the creation of the virtualenv (and related set-up) because I do it on a regular basis?

Comment: Yeah I agree, it's hard to give it a definition, but yes, I mean if you install it either for working locally or on sandbox, staging or production environments, that would count as a "real" download. But environments like those in CI servers, those are volatile and may discard the installed package after a very short time once it performs a few tasks.

Comment: Check out the [pypi ranking page](http://pypi-ranking.info/alltime)

Comment: Related discussion: https://discuss.python.org/t/tracking-interactive-vs-ci-use-of-pip-and-thus-pypi-downloads/7179

Answer (score 22):

I could possibly be 7 years late, but there's now a website called [pypistats](https://pypistats.org/) that gives you how many downloads your PyPi package has. [image: django's statistics and downloads according to the pypistats.org]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **vanity**:

To Install:
`pip install vanity`

To Run:
`vanity name-of-package`

**Note:** *The Python Packaging Index is to be moved from the current PyPi site to [Warehouse](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/), so these stats may be slightly off during this migration. The **Warehouse** pre-production site can be found [here](https://pypi.org/).*

Comment: I am only getting errors, no matter the package (python 3.7)

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer depending on your library's popularity...:

When your package makes it to the 360 most popular ones, it will [get in this list](https://pythonwheels.com/) If not, it is bellow that number... :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility to check this is to use [pypinfo](https://github.com/ofek/pypinfo/blob/master/README.rst) which is a command-line tool that provides access to the dataset and can generate several useful queries

**Install:**

```
$ python -m pip install pypinfo
```

**Usage:**

```
$ pypinfo <package>
```